# Using OVMF on Ubuntu to build a gaming virtual machine

Tags: boot, nvidia, uefi, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Recently, I bought a new `VGA Card`, and I decided to create a system that sometimes in the past I've tried to build without any success: a Linux system with a VGA Pass through setup. In this setup, I'd like to "pass" one Physical Drive to boot from (I'd build two virtual machines, one that would boot from a 2TB Hard Drive with `Netrunner 16` installed, the other one that would boot from a 500GB Hard Drive with `Windows 10` Enterprise installed, both connected with `SATA cables` to the PC): other hypervisors like `VMware` and `VirtualBox` permit this thing, and I know that `QEMU/KVM` can too.

I followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266916) tutorial , then I added the `VGA Card` with `virt-manager`, and my state is this: I have graphical output from both `SPICE` and HDMI1, but I can't boot anything: I can't boot a virtual Hard Disk with `Windows 10` that I created with a `SeaBIOS` setup, I can't boot a Windows 10 or Windows 7 DVD, I can't even boot my physical 2TB Hard Drive. I'm literally stuck at the `UEFI Interactive Shell`, that appears after some fleeting error messages like

```
Boot Failed: EFI Hard Drive
```

and

```
Boot Failed: EFI DVD/CDROM
```

My hardware is:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z77M-D3H
- RAM: 8 GB
- CPU: Intel Core i7-3770 @ 3.40 GHz
- Linux Distribution: Lubuntu 15.04
- GPU1 (used by Linux Host and connected to the monitor via VGA cable): an ASUS one whose GPU is nVidia GeForce GT220
- GPU2 (that should be used by the virtual machines and connected via HDMI cable): an ASUS one whose GPU is nVidia GeForce GTX750Ti

My current `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` is

```
intel_iommu=on pci-stub.ids=[...] pcie_acs_override=downstream i915.enable_hd_vgaarb=1 quiet splash
```

My Virtual Machine Configuration see [here](http://pastebin.com/2jvA7R6d). At the very bottom of this link, you'll find also a Imgur link to the UEFI Interactive Shell screen I'm stuck at, that I can't post directly here due to my low reputation.

Hoping that someone can help me, I thank you all in advance for having been read me till here, and I apologize for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been solved successfully. The reason you can't boot Windows 7 with OVMF when you installed it with SeaBios is that SeaBios isn't UEFI compliant, while OVMF *requeeds* a UEFI installation (hence an EFI partition to boot from). In fact, I can now boot successfully both Netrunner - by booting it from an EFI bootloader - and Windows 10 - with its own EFI bootloader -.